# Unable to view source code in texstudio latex

Tags: code, source

I am using Texstudio 4.2.2. I write my source code and compile it successfully and view it many times as PDF. After a few days, I got my paper revision. When I open the text studio my source code only shows????????? and when I compile it the PDF can be viewed successfully, but I don't know how to work in my source code. For better understanding screenshot[image] is attached. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That did not compile successfully (the red error message).  Copy your tex file to a backup.  It looks like something has gotten confused about the character encoding.  Which operating system are you using?

Comment: I am using Windows 2010 64-bit operating system.

Comment: I copy in other editors too but not working. I just need to view the source code once.

Comment: If you open it directly (don't copy and paste) in another editor, does it look OK?

Comment: No, not working. In another editor, the same problem and can view PDS like I shown in the screenshot.

Comment: What text editors are you using?  https://stackoverflow.com/q/3710374/2336725 suggests going to Notepad and then using Save As to see the encoding.  You can try changing what encoding you're using there.  You can also try opening the file in Notepad++.

Comment: I am using Texstudio 4.2.2 editor. I also tried your method but not working as well.